# Using Rank Math REgex for subfolder redirects to home

Tags: redirect, wordpress, regex, redirection

So short summary: im a SEO specialist working on a website that has over 1000 404 pages due to a translator app. The subfolders /de/ /fr/ /es/ /en/ and URL's within the subfolder need to be redirected to the homepage. Because it is not possible to load up a CSV file in Rank Math I thought why not use REgex... however I don't know what to place in Rank Math.

So please anyone write the REgex code for me :)
Example: website.shop/de/ needs to redirect to website.shop/ and website.shop/de/example/ also

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using WordPress plugins, SEO and SEO tools will be much more on topic on the https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help sister site